# How can I convert a RTMP stream to video file using FFmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am trying to convert an RTMP stream to a video file using FFmpeg, but keep getting an error,

`rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app: Broken pipe`

on using:

```
ffmpeg  -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app -acodec copy -vcodec copy test.mp4
```

streaming using FFmpeg as:

```
ffmpeg -i ./video.mp4 -c copy -f flv -listen 1 -flvflags no_duration_filesize  rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ffmpeg  -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app  test.mp4
```

Copy only:

```
ffmpeg  -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app -map 0:v -c copy -map 0:a -c copy -strict -2 test.mp4
```